# Does GNOME Tweak Tool work with GNOME Shell built from GIT?

Tags: 10.10, gnome

I'd like to try GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 10.10 again, after having discarded it due to the waste of space the non-configurable fonts were causing (I'm using a netbook). I read about GNOME Tweak Tool so I wondered if I could use it to customize the Shell interface. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I just run 10.04 LTS or BSD on netbooks.  You CAN choose not to have the "New" desktop environment gnome shell if that's what you're talking about, but I didn't think that happened until 11...Anyway, I have acceptably small fonts by default on an Acer Aspire.  Maybe it's some other weirdness.

Answer (score 1):

Just like GNOME Shell, you should be able to compile the GNOME Tweak Tool from its [git repository](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-tweak-tool), as well. I'd see no reason for any incompatibilities if you're using the latest version of both, since it seems both are supported by GNOME.